How to redirect non-www to www for root domain and www to non-www for subdomains with htaccess
with .htaccess I need to redirect non-www to www for the root domain
for example domain.com to www.domain.com
and redirect with www to non-www for subdomains
for example www.en.domain.com to en.domain.com
at the same time, and not hardcoding the domain
Thanks

www is also a subdomain and unnecessary since ~1990

Thank you brother for your comment, but I cannot do that since this particular case, so as not to lose the search engines indexed pages
